# Хочу сделать таймер, по моим задумкам число в Label должно отсчитывать от 5 до 1, но при нажатии

Tags: java, javafx

Хочу сделать таймер, по моим задумкам число в Label должно отсчитывать от 5 до 1, но при нажатии на кнопку программа просто застывает на 5 секунд и все. Помогите пожалуйста, кто знает

```
package sample.SupportClasses;

public class Timers extends LocationsLoader {

    public void timerGoingLocation(){
        controller.goingLabelOne.setVisible(true);
        controller.goingLabelSec.setVisible(true);
        controller.goingLabelTwo.setVisible(true);
        for(int i = 5; i != 0; i--){
            controller.goingLabelSec.setText("" + i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        controller.goingLabelOne.setVisible(false);
        controller.goingLabelSec.setVisible(false);
        controller.goingLabelTwo.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: невозможность воспроизвести проблему очень затрудняет поиск ее поиск и устранение. почему вы думаете , что проблема в именно этом коде? что это за мифический контроллер, к которому вы обращаетесь?

Comment: Делайте операцию обновления в другом потоке или вообще запускайте таймер в отдельном потоке и обновляйте с того потока `Label`

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как нашёл, то что мне нужно, почти

```
package sample.SupportClasses;

    import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
    import javafx.animation.Timeline;
    import javafx.util.Duration;

    import java.util.TimerTask;

    public class Timers extends LocationsLoader {

        public void timerGoingLocation(int sec){
            timer(sec);
        }
        public void timer(int sec){
            controller.goingLabelOne.setVisible(true);
            controller.goingLabelSec.setVisible(true);
            controller.goingLabelTwo.setVisible(true);
            final int[] time = {sec};
            controller.goingLabelSec.setText("" + sec);
            Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                   new KeyFrame(
                           Duration.millis(1000), ae -> {
                       time[0]--;
                       System.out.println("" + (time[0]));
                        controller.goingLabelSec.setText("" + (time[0]));
                        if(time[0] == 0){
                            showLabel();
                        }

                   }
                   )
            );
        timeline.setCycleCount(sec);
        timeline.play();
        }
        public void showLabel(){
            controller.goingLabelOne.setVisible(false);
            controller.goingLabelSec.setVisible(false);
            controller.goingLabelTwo.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Перерисовка отрабатывает в основном потоке после окончания работы метода. Переменная у вас меняется, но не перерисовывается. Надо вынести таймер в отдельный поток, и после изменения значения принудительны вызывать перерисовку.